# Root route and different initialRoute creates strange WidgetTree

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I'm trying to navigate between different screens using named routes.

I'm defining a root-Route (you may call it fallback route(?)), some other routes and an initialRoute, linking to a different screen than the root-Route.

[image]

The widget tree seems to load the root-route as well. But why?

[image]

TicketsScreen has many Widgets and I don't want them to be loaded beforehand.

BTW: This is only an example. When having multiple routes, it still loads both of the mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `/tasks` has a leading `/`.

The navigation system pushes everything that's there, let me explain.

If you had there routes:

- `/`
- `/tasks`
- `/tasks/new`

navigating to `/tasks/new` will push all of three.

If you want to keep "single" routes, you should use top level qualifiers. In your case that would be removing the `/` from `/tasks`.

This mechanism is useful to push a path and avoid strange pops if, for example,
you navigate to `/tasks/new` from a shortcut (not from `/tasks`) and then pop back. Would it be good to pop to the starting point? Would it be better if popping from a new task will lead to the tasks page?

That's a brief explanation of what the navigator tries to do, I guess.